# Error in Facebook Webhook

Tags: json, facebook, curl, webhooks, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm following the steps given by Facebook's webhook setup found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup. No more, no less.

And I'm having a hard time in this step:

[image]

When I enter the following line `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:1337/webhook" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}'` in the command line, I get this error:

[image]

What could the issue be?

Comment: The curl errors at the end look weird, "Could not resolve host: page" - as if it did not understand/ misinterpret the JSON, and took parts of it to mean something else (apparently it seems to think `page` was a host name here.)  Is your cURL version up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the ' from the command like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:1337/webhook" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}
```